# Ember-skeleton refresh time

Tags: ember.js

With all the concatenation of js and css files into a single file, either app.js or app.css, Ember-skeleton is way too slow to use for development. Is the Assetfile reprocessed each time we refresh the browser? Does anyone experience the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the images inside the static folder. I moved the img folder to the assets folder and everything is back to normal speed. I don't think the static folder belong to the app folder.